# Should I use ArrayList<?> or List<?>

Tags: java, android, optimization

I'm developing for Android and wondered, what are the main differences between an `ArrayList` and a `List`?

Comment: Have you looked at their respective documentations? That should answer the question immediately.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think thats necesserily true, for someone who doesn't know about interfaces etc the documentation looks like any other class.

Comment: @Jon Well if you don’t know about interfaces then the whole discussion is moot anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I just don't think people should assume something is obvious to everyone else just because it's obvious to them.

Comment: @Jon I’m not assuming it’s obvious, I’m assuming that you can’t program Java without knowing this. This doesn’t make this a bad question by the way, it’s merely that Stack Overflow is badly suited to teach the fundaments of programming – books or tutorials can do this much better.

Comment: Id correct that by saying you can't program Java well without knowing this, however you could easily get through programming by always using implementations of interfaces such as **ArrayList** without even realising what interfaces are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the handling of objects collection in Java, Collection interface have been provided. This is available in `java.util package`.

**"List"** is an interface, which extends collection interface, provides some sort of extra methods than collection interface to work with collections. Where as **"ArrayList"** is the actual implementation of "List" interface.

The **ArrayList class has only a few methods in addition to the methods available in the List** interface. There is not much difference in this. The only difference is, you are creating a reference of the parent interface in the first one and a reference of the class which implements the List (i.e) the ArrayList class in the second. If u use the first, you will be able to call the methods available in the List interface and you cannot make calls to the new methods available in the ArrayList class.Where as,  if you use the second one, you are free to use all the methods available in the ArrayList.

**EDIT:**

In Java Applications development, when you are supposed to pass the collection framework objects as arguments to the methods, then it is better to go with

```
List tempList = new ArrayList();
somemethodcall(tempList);
```

because, in future due to performance constraints, if you are changing the implementation to use linkedlist or some other classes which implements List interface, instead of ArrayList, you can change at only one point (i.e) only the instantiation part. Else you will be supposed to change at all the areas, where ever, you have used the specific class implementation as method arguments.

Comment: And what are those few methods which ArrayList adds? .forEach and .clone (a shallow copy) are the main ones.

Answer (score 8):

user370305 gives an exact explanation. This may also help you understand the collections hierarchy in Java.

[image: collections hierarchy]

Answer (score 3):

`List` is interface which `ArrayList` implements.  If you are trying to create a method which needs a `List` of some kind but you are not bothered what implemntation is actually used then use `List`.

If you are actually instantiating a class then you have to pick some implementation of `List` one of which is `ArrayList`

```
List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

would be an example.

You can not instantiate an interface and so would get an error if you tried to do the following:

```
List<String> l2 = new List<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_lists_vs._dynamic_arrays) about that, where the arraylist is called "dynamic array".
If you are trying to optimize your application you should take a look at the table next to the article.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an interface and `ArrayList` is an implementation of the `List` interface. The `ArrayList` class has only a few methods in addition to the methods available in the `List` interface.

Have a look at the short article on [*JavaBeat* - Difference Between List and ArrayList?](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/9-difference-between-list-and-arraylist-/)